# Как средствами css обрезать ползунок

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, range

[image: Полоса ползунка]
Как средствами `CSS` обрезать данную полосу ползунка не применяя к нему `clip-path`? Т.к. при применении данного свойства, `THUMB` (ползунок, кнопка и т.п.) так же обрезается и его нельзя переместить ниже полосы:

```js
$(function() {
  var r = $('input[type="range"]');
  r.on('mouseenter', function() {
    var p = r.val();
    r.on('click', function() {
      p = r.val();
      bg(p);
    });
    r.on('mousemove', function() {
      p = r.val();
      console.log(p)
      bg(p);
    });
  });

  function bg(n) {
    r.css({
      'background-image': '-webkit-linear-gradient(left ,#ceb8ee 0%,#435993 ' + n + '%,#e8e8e8 ' + n + '%, #e8e8e8 100%)'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
a:hover,
a:visited,
a:focus,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* Main window*/

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: auto;
  margin: auto;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 768px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#exp_js .lines {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 18.5rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: left;
  height: 4.5rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
}

#exp_js .lines:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 20rem;
  line-height: normal;
}

#exp_js .lines:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 18rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  line-height: normal;
}

#exp_js .lines:nth-of-type(4) {
  width: 20rem;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

#exp_js .border-lines {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 18.4rem;
  text-align: left;
  height: 1.5rem;
}

#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(5) {
  left: 0.3rem;
}

#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(5):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 75%;
  z-index: 0;
  border-left: 1px dashed #b0b0b0;
}

#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(6) {
  width: 20.13rem;
}

#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(6):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 140%;
  left: 0.06rem;
  top: 65%;
  z-index: 0;
  border-left: 1px dashed #b0b0b0;
}

#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(6):after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  top: 170%;
  z-index: 2;
  border-left: 1.5px solid #fff;
}

#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(7) {
  width: 23rem;
}

#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(7):before {
  left: 0.04rem;
}

#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(7):after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  top: 150%;
  z-index: 2;
  border-left: 1.5px solid #fff;
}

#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(8) {
  width: 15.27rem;
}

#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(8):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  top: 35%;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 0;
  border-right: 1px dashed #b0b0b0;
  border-left: none;
}

#exp_js .border-lines:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 1px dashed #b0b0b0;
}

#exp_js input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e8e8e8 0%, #e8e8e8 25%, #e8e8e8 50%, #e8e8e8 100%);
  outline: none;
  transition: .1s;
}

#exp_js input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e8e8e8 0%, #e8e8e8 25%, #e8e8e8 50%, #e8e8e8 100%);
  outline: none;
  transition: .1s;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 68%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 68%);
}

#exp_js input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e8e8e8 0%, #e8e8e8 25%, #e8e8e8 50%, #e8e8e8 100%);
  outline: none;
  transition: .1s;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 68%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 68%);
}

#exp_js input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e8e8e8 0%, #e8e8e8 25%, #e8e8e8 50%, #e8e8e8 100%);
  outline: none;
  transition: .1s;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 68%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 68%);
}

#exp_js input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e8e8e8 0%, #e8e8e8 25%, #e8e8e8 50%, #e8e8e8 100%);
  outline: none;
  transition: .1s;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 68%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 68%);
}

#exp_js input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 22px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #435993;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .1s;
  z-index: 10;
}

#exp_js input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 22px;
  height: 25px;
  background: url(../img/active.png) no-repeat;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: 10;
}

#exp_js input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover,
#exp_js input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
  /*   width: 16px;
height: 16px; */
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="exp_js">
  <article>
    <div class="lines">Не владею</div>
    <div class="lines">Использую готовые<br> решения</div>
    <div class="lines">Использую готовые решения и умею переделывать</div>
    <div class="lines">Пишу сложный JS с нуля</div>
    <div class="border-lines"></div>
    <div class="border-lines"></div>
    <div class="border-lines"></div>
    <div class="border-lines"></div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" id="ranger">
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Я вот почему-то не вижу никакого ползунка (Chrome, Win10).

Comment: я тоже не вижу почему-то сейчас. Но в любом случае, я уже переписал код на JS, и столкнулся все равно с той же проблемой - реализации градиентной составляющей. [Вопрос и код по этой ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/698223/slider-%D0%BD%D0%B0-js-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC)