# Slider на JS, изменение градиента по указанным значениям

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, style

Всем снова привет! Переписал код для слайдера, но теперь не могу допереть, как сделать градиент между цветами **#e8e8e8** и **#445994** при движении ползунка.
Кто-нибудь может подсказать, что добавить в JS ? :)
Причем загвоздка в том, что начальный цвет от начала полосы должен быть #e8e8e8, а конечный цвет в конце полосы **#445994**.
Т.е. по середине полосы должен быть цвет между ними #8986c3 примерно этот.

Я уже голову сломал с разными вариациями, но не работает как надо.

*Ах да, как сделать, чтобы ползунок уходил чуть левее от полоски вначале и чуть правее в конце? (чтобы кончик типа капли заканчивался в конце полосы слайдера)*

```js
var thumb = slider.firstElementChild;

    thumb.onmousedown = function(e){

        var shiftX = e.pageX - getCoords(thumb).left;
        var sliderCoords = getCoords(slider);
        var thumbStyle = thumb.style;

        changeAtMove(e);
        function changeAtMove(e){
            if((e.pageX - shiftX) < sliderCoords.left){
                thumbStyle.left = -10;
            }else if((e.pageX - shiftX + thumb.offsetWidth) > sliderCoords.right){
                thumbStyle.left = slider.offsetWidth - thumb.offsetWidth + 'px';
            }else {
                thumbStyle.left = e.pageX - sliderCoords.left - shiftX + 'px';
            }
        }

        document.onmousemove = function(e){
            changeAtMove(e);
        }

        document.onmouseup = thumb.onmouseup = function(){
            document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
        }
        return false;
    };

    thumb.ondragstart = function(){return false;}

    function getCoords(elem){
        var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            top:   box.top + pageYOffset,
            left:  box.left + pageXOffset,
            right: box.right + pageXOffset
        };
    }
```

```css
body {
font-size: 10px;
}
#exp_js img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 2.8rem;
}
#exp_js h4 {
  margin-top: 2.8rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 4.8rem;
}
#exp_js .lines {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 18.5rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: left;
  height: 4.5rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
  z-index: 5;
}
#exp_js .lines:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 20rem;
  line-height: normal;
  z-index: 5;
}
#exp_js .lines:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 18rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  line-height: normal;
  z-index: 5;
}
#exp_js .lines:nth-of-type(4) {
  width: 20rem;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 5;
}
#exp_js .border-lines {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 18.4rem;
  text-align: left;
  height: 1.5rem;
  z-index: 3;
}
#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(5) {
  left: 0.3rem;
}
#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(5):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 75%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-left: 1px dashed #b0b0b0;
}
#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(6) {
  width: 20.13rem;
}
#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(6):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 140%;
  left: 0.06rem;
  top: 65%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-left: 1px dashed #b0b0b0;
}
#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(6):after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  top: 180%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-left: 1.5px solid #fff;
}
#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(7) {
  width: 23rem;
}
#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(7):before {
  left: 0.04rem;
}
#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(7):after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  top: 160%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-left: 1.5px solid #fff;
}
#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(8) {
  width: 15.27rem;
}
#exp_js .border-lines:nth-of-type(8):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  top: 35%;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-right: 1px dashed #b0b0b0;
  border-left: none;
}
#exp_js .border-lines:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-left: 1px dashed #b0b0b0;
}
#exp_js .slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #e8e8e8 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e8e8e8 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(left, #e8e8e8 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
  outline: none;
  transition: .1s;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e8e8e8', endColorstr='#445994', GradientType=1);
  top: 6.4rem;
  z-index: 2;
}
#exp_js .slider:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0.4rem;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  outline: none;
  transform: rotate(-0.5deg);
  z-index: -2;
}
#exp_js .thumb {
  position: relative;
  width: 2.2rem;
  height: 2.2rem;
  top: 2rem;
  left: -10px;
  background: #bababa;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bababa 0%, #bababa 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bababa 0%, #bababa 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(bottom, #bababa 0%, #bababa 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#bababa', endColorstr='#bababa', GradientType=0);
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#exp_js .thumb:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 0.101rem;
  bottom: 1.53rem;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1rem solid #bababa;
  border-left: 1rem solid transparent;
  border-right: 1rem solid transparent;
}
#exp_js .thumb:after {
  content: "";
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  left: 1.1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="exp_js">
 <article>
<div id="slider" class="slider">
     <div class="thumb"></div>
       </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Потратив совсем немного времени получилось вот так:

```
var range = [ [68, 232], [89, 232], [148, 232] ];
var color = [];
range.forEach(function(v, i) {
    color[i] = Math.round( v[0] + mouseLeftPosition * (v[1] - v[0]) );
});
document.querySelector('body').style.background = "rgb(" + color.join(', ') + ")";
```

https://codepen.io/kirya-dev/pen/eENGGO

Comment: Это лучше добавить в предыдущий ответ, а не создавать новый

Comment: спасибо, в общем конечно теперь работает, но немного кривовато стало почему-то :( Скролл прыгает, левая позиция встает ползунка как надо, правая - нет (крайняя правая в конце). Плюсом ко всему цвет меняется от начала экрана до конца экрана, а не от начала слайдера до конца слайдера)

Comment: Тем не менее, все равно немного не так :) Цвет должен заполняться ДО ползунка :) В этом то и вопрос, что должны считываться координаты ползунка, и кстати ON считывается на IE11

Comment: Допилите как вам нужно, я лишь показал как цвет менять.